# Accessing Docker container from outside/browser

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, docker-compose

My Docker Compose config:

```
version: "3"
services:
  django1:
    build: .
    command: "python ./test1/manage.py runserver"
    ports:
      - "8006:8000"
    expose:
      - "8006"
    networks:
      main_network:
        ipv4_address: 20.20.0.3
  django2:
    build: .
    command: "python ./test2/manage.py runserver"
    ports:
      - "8007:8000"
    expose:
      - "8007"
    networks:
      main_network:
        ipv4_address: 20.20.0.2

networks:
  main_network:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 20.20.0.0/24
```

and this is my command for accessing Docker from outside

```
docker run --name testname -p 8077:8007 my_image_name
```

But still when I visit from browser **20.20.0.2:8077** but it does not work

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you access it by localhost:8077?

Comment: No, I can't. I checked it . But It did not work

Answer (score 0):

The Docker-internal IP addresses only work on one very specific host/OS configuration; you shouldn’t try to access them directly and there’s almost never a need to specify them in configuration.  (You can in fact delete all of the `networks:` blocks, [Compose provides reasonable defaults for you](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/).)

Since you publish `ports:` you can use your *host’s* IP address and the published (first) port number.  If your browser and Docker are on the same host then `localhost` will work here too (`http://localhost:8077`), unless you’re using Docker Toolbox, in which case you need the `docker-machine ip` address (often 192.168.99.100).

If you can access the container-private IP addresses at all (your browser and Docker are on the same native-Linux host and you’re not running a more complex Docker-in-Docker or VM-based setup) then you need the port number inside the container, the second number in `ports:`.  This also applies to container-to-container communication, where the Compose service names should be used as host names (`django1` can call `http://django2:8000`).

Comment: I deleted all  `networks`  blocks, and  I tried `localhost:8077`. It again did not work. However, I did not use `docker run --name testname -p 8077:8007 my_image_name
` It worked when I write `localhost:expose_port`. After I deploy project, I can reach Docker Container?